# Axis2 generating wsu:Id="SecurityToken-..." in request header

Tags: security, apache-axis

We are using axis2 with WS policy as follows:

```
context.setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY, loadPolicy(PLAIN_TEXT_POLICY_FILE));
```

with loadpPolicy code:

```
InputStream file = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
  StAXOMBuilder builder = new StAXOMBuilder(file);
  Policy result = PolicyEngine.getPolicy(builder.getDocumentElement());
```

When we perform a call we are seeing:

> wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1"

We want instead of wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" to see something like: wsu:Id="SecurityToken-d61ff167-34c7-430b-b3ad-50c8882ed5t9"

How can this be achieved? Do we need to update the policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header was successfully formed manually from Java code while using no policy:

```
stub._getServiceClient().addHeader(createRequestHeader());
```

The createRequestHeader has the following code:

```
// Defines some namespace and URL constants
  String WS_SEC_NS = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
  String WS_SOAP_URL = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

  SOAPFactory soapFact = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP12Factory();

  // namespace objects creation
  OMNamespace ns = soapFact.createOMNamespace(WS_SEC_NS, "wsse");
  OMNamespace nsu = soapFact.createOMNamespace(WS_SEC_NS, "wsu");
  OMNamespace nsoap = soapFact.createOMNamespace(WS_SOAP_URL, "soap");

  // Header definition and sub elements
  SOAPHeaderBlock wssHeader = soapFact.createSOAPHeaderBlock("Security", ns);
  wssHeader.addAttribute("mustUnderstand", "1", nsoap);

  OMElement timeStampElement = soapFact.createOMElement("Timestamp", nsu);
  // add random UUID as security ID
  timeStampElement.addAttribute("Id", "Timestamp-" + UUID.randomUUID(), nsu);
  // sub elements of timestamp
  OMElement expires = soapFact.createOMElement("Expires", nsu);
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  // expiry period is now + 5 minutes
  cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
  expires.setText(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(cal.getTime())));
  OMElement created = soapFact.createOMElement("Created", nsu);
  created.setText(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(new Date())));

  OMElement usernameToken = soapFact.createOMElement("UsernameToken", ns);
  // add random UUID as security token ID
  usernameToken.addAttribute("Id", "SecurityToken-" + UUID.randomUUID(), nsu);
  // sub elements of username token
  OMElement username = soapFact.createOMElement("Username", ns);
  username.setText(user);
  OMElement password = soapFact.createOMElement("Password", ns);
  password.setText(this.password);
  password.addAttribute(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE_ATTR, WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT, null);
  OMElement nonce = soapFact.createOMElement("Nonce", ns);
  // fill the nonce as a random encoded UUID
  nonce.setText(HashUtils.createEncodedUUID());
  OMElement createdUser = soapFact.createOMElement("Created", nsu);
  createdUser.setText(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(new Date())));

  // adding sub elements
  usernameToken.addChild(username);
  usernameToken.addChild(password);
  usernameToken.addChild(nonce);
  usernameToken.addChild(createdUser);

  timeStampElement.addChild(created);
  timeStampElement.addChild(expires);

  wssHeader.addChild(timeStampElement);
  wssHeader.addChild(usernameToken);
```

And the following method is used for hash:

```
     public static String createEncodedUUID()
   {
      log.trace("Enter Method createEncodedUUID");
      String randomId = String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());
      MessageDigest md = null;
      String result = "";
      try
      {
         md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
         md.update(randomId.getBytes());
         byte[] byteNonce = md.digest();
         result = String.valueOf(Base64.encodeBase64(byteNonce));
      }
      catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
      {
         log.error("NoSuchAlgorithmException. Error calling createEncodedUUID.", e);
      }

      log.trace("Return Method createEncodedUUID. Result: {}", result);
      return result;
   }
```